# WinXP- delete single entry in event log

Tags: windows-xp, event-log

Is there a way to delete a single event from the system event viewer in Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can delete an entry in the System log. But you may [filter the ones you don't like](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/nt_filteringevents_how_ev.mspx).